# Couchbase Multi-Get over HTTP? Is it possible. Unable to install SDK

Tags: couchbase

Can Multi-Gets in Couchbase by performed via an HTTP Request? If so what is the Request/URL pattern? For installation restriction reasons I am unable to install the SDK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will probably help you, http://www.couchbase.com/communities/cn/q-and-a/rest-api-getting-data

What installation restrictions mean you can't use the SDK? I would recommend the SDK over circumventing the standard couchbase interaction methods.

Comment: Ah yes. http://www.couchbase.com/docs//couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-views-querying-rest-api.html